# PowerMockito: InvalidUseOfMatchersException while mocking static method with string [] argument

Tags: java, maven, junit, powermockito

org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: Misplaced argument matcher detected here:

I am facing the `org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException` exception while doing powermockito on following static method.

```
public class ShellCommandUtil {
    public static ArrayList executeShellCommand(String[] shellcmd) { 
        ArrayList output = new ArrayList(); 
         //removed the actual logic of sending shellcommand to the system   getting the result;
        return output;
    }
}
```

TestMethod written is defined below

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
 @PrepareForTest(ShellCommandUtil.class)
 public class ShellDataTest{
@Test
 public void testExecuteShellCommand() {
     ArrayList resultData = new ArrayList();
     resultData.add("data1");
     resultData.add("data2");
     PowerMockito.mockStatic(ShellCommandUtil.class);
     PowerMockito.when(ShellCommandUtil.executeShellCommand(Mockito.any(String [].class))).thenReturn(resultData);
    }
 }
```

Can you please help what is defined wrong here in this line

```
PowerMockito.when(ShellCommandUtil.executeShellCommand(Mockito.any(String[].class))).thenReturn(resultData);
```

In pom.xml, I have added the following dependency

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.powermock/powermock-mockito-release-full -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-mockito-release-full</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.4</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

Please let me know your thoughts in this problem.

Thanks,
Rajeswari

Comment: Add the complete stacktrace

Comment: And, the usual caveat: write testable code (https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLD0011D00849E1B79 ) then you don't need to bother with PowerMock.

Comment: @Rajeswari - add your imports used in both the classes

Answer (score 1):

According to the PowerMockito class's Javadoc, you should have written

```
PowerMockito.when(ShellCommandUtil.class, "executeShellCommand", Mockito.any(String [].class)).thenReturn(resultData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried creating a fresh project with following details, do confirm if this differs from your implementation except for class names. Since this works for me -

***Base Class -***

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Shell {

    public static ArrayList executeShellCommand(String[] shellcmd) {
        ArrayList output = new ArrayList();
        //removed the actual logic of sending shell command to the system   getting the result;
        return output;
    }
}
```

***Test Class -***

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Shell.class)
public class ShellTest {

    @Test
    public void testExecuteShellCommand() {
        ArrayList resultData = new ArrayList();
        resultData.add("data1");
        resultData.add("data2");
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Shell.class);
        PowerMockito.when(Shell.executeShellCommand(Mockito.any(String[].class))).thenReturn(resultData);
        System.out.println("All went fine.");
    }
}
```

***pom.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>powermock-mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mock</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.powermock/powermock-mockito-release-full -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-mockito-release-full</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: The code shared above is pretty much the same except I run with        import org.testng.annotations.Test;

Comment: @Rajeswari - in that case you need to share the details as mentioned in the comments for your question